# User ID in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, actionlink

I'm developing an app, and after user have signed in i want to redirect them to a page where they can update their profiles, for this I want to use the ID of the user who is logged in to retrieve their details.

Since I'm trying to use their ID like that, i don't know if the best method is still to show the ID in the URL or **actionLink**, my Edit ActionResult is:

```
// GET: ProfileFormViewModel/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //My code to load the user details

        return View(profileFormViewModel);
    }
```

Could this mean that if a user changes the URL they would get the other user's details?

And since i'm trying to retrieve the user ID from the logged in user, do I even need to receive a `int` parameter in the ActionResult Method, could i just leave it like:

```
// GET: ProfileFormViewModel/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //get logged in user

        return View(profileFormViewModel);
    }
    public ActionResult Edit(ProfileFormViewModel profileFormViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                 //Go save it
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My route config is as follows, so if i don't send an int ID in the ActionResult link it will give me an error

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: you should not be accepting the user id as a parameter.. it should also not be on your `ProfileFormViewModel`... you should decorate the Edit actions with some kind of [Authorize] attribute as well...  always retrieve the UserID from your user manager..

Comment: there are exceptions to the rule when it comes to allowing admins or super users the ability to edit user profiles.  if that is the case, you should probably write some kind of custom authorization attribute or action filter and accept the ID you want to edit as a parameter.

Comment: Your second attempt should not be problem because `id` is an optional parameter.

Comment: Alright, so according to what you're saying i should be using the second approach, right? or should i make the input parameter optional, like this: < public ActionResult Edit(int? id) > and then retrieve the UserID from the user manager? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Could this mean that if a user changes the URL they would get the
>   other user's details?

The answer is **yes**. If you don't want this to happen, you can do this:

1. Check the input `id` with current logged in user `id`.
2. If they match, show him his `Profile` and let him make any changes as he wishes.
3. If they don't match, it means he's trying to view another profile. You can return an error code, or just redirect him to another page.

However, from my viewpoint, when a user try to view another user's profile by changing the `id` in the URL, just let him **see** it. All he can do is **reading, editing is not allowed**.

> do I even need to receive an `int` parameter in the ActionResult Method?

**Yes**, you should. But to be clear, as I said: "**just let him see other profile**", you should separate this into 2 methods:

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile(int id)
{
    // This method allows user to view his or another user's profile
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
    // This method is called when user clicks Edit in his profile.
    // It returns a View for editing (data in some controls like textboxes, dropdownlist,...)
}
```